# I am trying to make a connection in Flutter using python (flask) for back end

Tags: python, flutter, flask

Can anyone help me with this error...
I have tried many different codes but till now nothing works...
I have tried running on proxy servers in emulators too that didn't work 
Following is the Flutter file -:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

class New extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: InkWell(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Text('hello', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0)),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 50.0,),
              Center(
                child: Text('This is new', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        onTap: (){
          news();
        },
      ),
    );
  }


  Future<http.Response> news() async
  {
    String url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/getMenuData'; //192.168.0.105:5000 another port that i tried        
    var body;
    print('Start toh hua');
    var bodyEncode = json.encode(body);
    Map<String, String> Headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };
    print('heyyyy');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print('byeeee');
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    print('done bhi ho gaya');
    print(responseJson);
    return response;
}

}
```

Following is the main.py file that I want to connect-:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def getMenuData():    
    # if request.method == 'GET':
    #     return jsonify(menuData)
    print('hello')
    return 'Success ho gaya'
    # return jsonify ({'name':'Success'})





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, debug=True)
```

the error that I am getting after running this file is -:

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
Reloaded 8 of 716 libraries in 2,024ms.
I/flutter (20787): Started
I/flutter (20787): heyyyy
E/flutter (20787): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 45448
E/flutter (20787):
```

// This is the full code that I am trying to run right now but it's not working.

Comment: that just mean's, for the client the server doesn't exists, try the link in your browser, the client and the server should be on the same network if you are using localhost

Comment: you are defining a get route but posting from client? and you are defining a root(/) route and posting to to '/getMenuData'?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have proxy servers in emulators too that didn't work". Are you running both processes in the same host or not?

Comment: both are on the same network and the server is running on the browser. and I have converted 'post' to 'get' now but it's still not working...

Comment: @lguananaut I have 'tried' running through the proxy servers but that wasn't successful either. Yes, they are running in the same host.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're not sending the headers.

And I think the url is wrong it should be just "/" not the function name.

if these didn't work you should try sending a request via Postman and see where is the problem.

Comment: okay, thank you...now it's running. the problem was of URL only.